# Proving that $ \lim_{R \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{\gamma_{R_{N}}} \frac{iRe^{i\theta}d\theta}{R^4e^{4i\theta}\sin(\pi Re^{i\theta}) } = 0 $

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits, summation, residue-calculus

I want to show that:

$$ S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{n}}{n^4} = - \frac {7\pi^4}{720} $$

In order to do that, I use the residue theorem method. I define the function:

$$ f(z) = \frac{1}{z^4\sin(\pi z)} $$

The poles are $0$ and $ \left\{z = n, n \in \mathbb{Z^{*}} \right\}$.
The residues are $$\text{Res}(f,0) = \frac{7\pi^3}{360}$$ and 
$$\text{Res}(f,n) = \frac{(-1)^n}{\pi n^4}, \qquad\forall n \in \mathbb{Z^{*}}.$$

I then define $\gamma_{R_N}$ to be the circle with center $z=0$ and radius $N<R<N+1$ for $N\in\mathbb{N}^*$, i.e.,

$$\gamma_{R_{N}} = \left\{z = Re^{i \theta}, \theta \in [0,2\pi] \right\}.$$

In order to use the residue theorem, I want to proove that:

$$ \lim_{R \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{\gamma_{R_{N}}} \frac{dz}{z^4\sin(\pi z) } = 0 $$

Here $z = Re^{i\theta} $ so I have to prove that:

$$ \lim_{R \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{\gamma_{R_{N}}} \frac{iRe^{i\theta}d\theta}{R^4e^{4i\theta}\sin(\pi Re^{i\theta}) } = 0 $$

How can I do that?

Thank you all!

Comment: can you show us why you pick this function? I guess it has something to do with the series you want (maybe fourier series or something), but maybe it's not the best function to pick and another one will do; in particular the sin in the denominator can give problems as it can get arbitrarily close to $0$ blowing up the function; if you had in the denominator $e^{i\pi\theta}$, for example, you wouldn't have this problem. So are you sure this is the function we need to consider?

Comment: Take a look here http://www.supermath.info/InfiniteSeriesandtheResidueTheorem.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution but I'll post it anyway; maybe you'll find it useful

Bound the modulus of the integral by something that tends to $0$ faster than $1/R$. If the modules of the integral is bounded by something that tends to $0$, the integral too will tend to $0$

In this case, show that $$|\sin(\pi z)| \ge \frac{e^{\pi R \sin \theta} - e^{-\pi R \sin \theta}}2$$

Hence you can write

$$\left | \int _{\gamma_R} \frac 1{z^4 \sin (\pi z)} \right | \le \int _{\gamma_R} \frac 2{R^4 (e^{\pi R \sin \theta} - e^{-\pi R \sin \theta})} dz $$

Unfortunaltey, the integrand blows up when $\theta = 0, \pi$ (i.e. when the sine is $0$). On the other hand, there are the only two points where there can be a problem; so define $$\tilde f(z) = \begin{cases} \frac 1{z^4 \sin (\pi z)} & \text{$\arg z = \theta \notin \{0, \pi\}$} \\ 0  & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Since $f(z) = \tilde f(z)$ almost everywhere, you have that

$$\int _{\gamma_R} \frac 1{z^4 \sin (\pi z)}dz= \int _{\gamma_R} \tilde f(z) dz$$

You can then bound the modulus of the latter integral (much in the same way as before) to find

$$ \left|\int _{\gamma_R} \tilde f(z) dz\right| \le \int _{\gamma_R} \frac 2{R^4 (e^{\pi R \sin \theta} - e^{-\pi R \sin \theta})} (1 - 1_{\{0, \pi\}}(\theta)) dz = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac {2(1 - 1_{\{0, \pi\}}(\theta))}{R^3 (e^{\pi R \sin \theta} - e^{-\pi R \sin \theta})} d\theta$$

Taking the limit as $R \to \infty$, **if** you can exchange the limit and the integral you would find the result you want i.e. the latter integral  tends to $0$, hence also the integral of $\tilde f(z)$ tends to $0$. hence also the integral of $f(z)$ tends to $0$.  Not sure how to prove that it's possible to exchange the limit and the integral though; lebesgue dominated convergence theorem doesn't help since the function is not bounded by something integrable. Not sure how to proceed; it may be that the integral doesn't go to $0$